# Copy paste in VBA depending on number in cells

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to have a VBA code check columns B,E,H,K,N from sheet1 for a number greater than 0, then copy and paste that cell, the one before and the one after in sheet2 in columns A,B and C?

Here is the code I've been using but it's taking the whole Row and that's not exactly what I want as it gives a lot of content that's unnecessary:

```
Sub Epicerie()

For Each Cell In Sheets("Liste").Range("B:B, E:E, H:H, K:K, N:N")

    If Cell.Value > 0 Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Listepret").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Liste").Select
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: "I want" is not a question. Read [ask] before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Epicerie()

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Sheets("Liste").Range("B:B, E:E, H:H, K:K, N:N")
    If Cell.Value > 0 Then
        With Sheets("Listepret")
            ' copy paste in 1 line to the next empty row at Column "A"
            Cell.Offset(, -1).Resize(1, 3).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```